# Find the path with minimum cost between multiple nodes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, graph-algorithm

Can you please tell me what is the name of algorithm or serie of algorithms for the next configuration ?

We have several clients ... We know the distance(cost) between each client ... And we know the start point.

I need to find the optimal route for the delivery boy which must leave from the start point and he must pass 1 time at each client.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called Hamilton cycle problem. Or travelling salesman problem.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response

Comment: if you have multiple delivery boys and have time windows and/or capacity restrictions etc you need to solve the more general vehicle routing problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem

Comment: Does the OPTIMAP solution ( http://www.gebweb.net/optimap/ ) answers to the general vehicle routing problem ? I've tested optimap several times and frankly got good results.